# PyTorch - derivative for aten::scatter_ is not implemented

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor, backpropagation

I am having problems backpropagating (`loss.backward()`) the error when my model uses the `aten::scatter_` function to compute the loss function.

First, I define my model where in the forward function, I use the `aten::scatter_` function to create the product across individuals with the same `id`.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.beta = nn.Linear(1, 1, bias=False)

    def forward(self, x, id):
        b = self.beta(torch.ones(1, 1))
        xb = x*b
        N = torch.unique(id).shape[0]
        scattering = torch.ones(N, 1, dtype=x.dtype)
        # Here!!!... I am computing the product across rows of the same id
        scattering_res = scattering.scatter_(0, id-1, xb, reduce='multiply' )
        loss = torch.sum(scattering_res)
        return loss
```

Here I create some tensors to apply the model and replicate the error message I am getting:

```
id = torch.tensor([1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5],dtype=torch.int64).reshape(10, 1)
x = torch.tensor([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], dtype=torch.float).reshape(10, 1)
y = torch.tensor([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],dtype=torch.float).reshape(10, 1)
net = Net() 
print(net)
optimizer = optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=0.01)
criterion = nn.MSELoss()

# Update params
optimizer.zero_grad()
loss = net(x, id)
loss.backward()
## RuntimeError: derivative for aten::scatter_ is not implemented
```

Do you know how to solve this issue? Some people have suggested I move the product operation to `numpy`, but I am still not convinced that this will actually solve my problem since the operation I need is a `product by group` of individuals from the same `id`.

Additionally, I came across a GitHub issue (https://github.com/rusty1s/pytorch_scatter/issues/63) where a similar problem was posted, but I couldn't adjust it to solve my problem.

---

Below you can see the whole traceback error message.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Untitled-2 in <cell line: 32>()
     <a href='untitled:Untitled-2?line=31'>32</a> optimizer.zero_grad()
     <a href='untitled:Untitled-2?line=32'>33</a> loss = net(x, id)
---> <a href='untitled:Untitled-2?line=33'>34</a> loss.backward()

File c:\Users\u0133260\Anaconda3\envs\pyt\lib\site-packages\torch\_tensor.py:396, in Tensor.backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph, inputs)
    387 if has_torch_function_unary(self):
    388     return handle_torch_function(
    389         Tensor.backward,
    390         (self,),
   (...)
    394         create_graph=create_graph,
    395         inputs=inputs)
--> 396 torch.autograd.backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph, inputs=inputs)

File c:\Users\u0133260\Anaconda3\envs\pyt\lib\site-packages\torch\autograd\__init__.py:173, in backward(tensors, grad_tensors, retain_graph, create_graph, grad_variables, inputs)
    168     retain_graph = create_graph
    170 # The reason we repeat same the comment below is that
    171 # some Python versions print out the first line of a multi-line function
    172 # calls in the traceback and some print out the last line
--> 173 Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(  # Calls into the C++ engine to run the backward pass
    174     tensors, grad_tensors_, retain_graph, create_graph, inputs,
    175     allow_unreachable=True, accumulate_grad=True)

RuntimeError: derivative for aten::scatter_ is not implemented
```

Crossposted at: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/derivative-for-aten-scatter-is-not-implemented/168133

Comment: Have you tried the out-of-place version, namely `torch.scatter`? https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.scatter.html?highlight=tensor+scatter#torch.Tensor.scatter